# Pass uploaded image from user gallery to another activity and then upload image to the firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

I am trying to pass user uploaded image into another activity and then to the fire base. This is a code snippet from my first activity where I am passing my other variables to next activity.

```
    String username = signup_username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String email = signup_email.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String password = signup_password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    int selectedId = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
    String radio_value = (String) radioButton.getText();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("username",username);
    bundle.putString("email",email);
    bundle.putString("password",password);
    bundle.putString("gender",radio_value);

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity_registration.this,activity_registration_next.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(activity_registration.this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have an user uploaded image in the same activity. The code snippets are:

```
 private void pickImageFromGallery()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_PICK_CODE);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode ==IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
    {
        picture_view.setImageURI(data.getData());
    }
}
```

Now, I want to pass this image to next activity and there upload to firebase. I also have other attributes in next page. The code snippet is given below:

```
 user = new Users();
 reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

  String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String email = "";
    String gender = "";

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null){
        username = bundle.getString("username");
        password = bundle.getString("email");
        email = bundle.getString("password");
        gender = bundle.getString("gender");
    }

    String first_name = firstname.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String middle = middle_init.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String last_name = lastname.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String phone = phone_num.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String university_value =university.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String category =classification.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();


    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setGender(gender);
    user.setFirst_name(first_name);
    user.setMiddle_init(middle);
    user.setLast_name(last_name);
    user.setPhone_num(phone);
    user.setUniversity(university_value);
    user.setClassification(category);
    reff.push().setValue(user);

    Toast.makeText(activity_registration_next.this,"Registration Complete!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an entire layout to an image/bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015626/converting-an-entire-layout-to-an-image-bitmap)

Comment: `picture_view.setImageURI(data.getData())` What is picture_view? And you are never using this stored uri.